# Issue on Pull request in Github

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

We have 2 pull requests.
Pull request1 has 3 files.
Pull request2 had 20 files and dependency on pull request 1 on 1 file.

Now we merged the pull request 1 to master. And then merged the pull request 2. When we merge pull request 2 the code which has updated in pull request 1 on dependency file got appended twice when we merge pull request 2. Our scripts are getting failed because of this.

What could be the reason for appending twice when we have dependency pull request?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, and we would probably have to see the files and diffs to give an exact answer.  But this sort of thing might happen if, e.g., the two pull requests were doing similar things to that one file.  For example, both PRs were doing similar logic to a certain method.  If you follow good workflow strategy, this problem usually does not come up.

Comment: 2 pull requests are doing 2 different changes. I checked with team. It looks like they have communicated and start appending changes on top of pull request 1 manually. They have not done git pull to update changes of pull request 2.  This could be reason for appending twice? Because their commit id may be different because they have not done git pull after merging pull request 1. Correct me if am wrong. When i check the pull request2 for this file i could see both pull request 1 changes and pull request 2  changes looks as new.

Comment: I still largely stick by my comment.  You should avoid making the same changes in more than one place.